# Getting "ECONNREFUSED" error when trying to upload to Wolkenkit Blob Server

Tags: post, server, request, blob, wolkenkit

I'm currently developing a Wolkenkit application which is run on my local machine.
I want to upload a file from the Wolkenkit app to the blob server (as documented [here](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/1.2.0/reference/building-a-client/storing-files/)).

When sending a POST request from the server to `https://local.wolkenkit.io:3001/`, Node.js gives me the error `ECONNREFUSED`.

I've tested the POST-Request with another program and it works there. Any idea why it doesn't work from the wolkenkit application itself?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you add the output of `netstat -tln` (linux) or `netstat -a -b -n` (windows) to your post? This will tell you if you have an application listening on `:3001`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Storing files](https://docs.wolkenkit.io/1.2.0/reference/building-a-client/storing-files/) sample you linked to shows code that is to be run in the browser, not in the backend itself. Of course, both should work, but there are a few minor differences you need to watch out for.

#### Fixing the host name

First, I suppose that `local.wolkenkit.io` in your case maps to `127.0.0.1`, which is the default for wolkenkit. That means that when you try to connect to this domain from within a Docker container, the container does not try to call out to the blog storage container, but it stays within itself. So, the first thing that needs to be fixed is the host name.

Basically, there are two options for this: You can either setup `local.wolkenkit.io` so that it resolves to the external IP address of your machine. This would work, but is pretty cumbersome. The other option is to directly address the appropriate container that is responsible for blob storage, by its *internal name*. The [internal name](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit/blob/069b0119bd90864862f3f50bf07b57bfa602a510/configuration/1.2.0/depot-file/container.js#L35) is `<name-of-your-app>-depot-file`. So you need to replace `https://local.wolkenkit.io:3001/` by `https://<...>-depot-file.wolkenkit.io:3001/`.

#### Fixing the port

Second, the port is wrong. This is because the blob storage service is [internally running on port 3000, externally on 3001](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit/blob/069b0119bd90864862f3f50bf07b57bfa602a510/configuration/1.2.0/depot-file/container.js#L55). So instead of `https://<...>-depot-file.wolkenkit.io:3001/` you need to use `https://<...>-depot-file.wolkenkit.io:3000/`.

Once you have done this you should not get any more errors like `ECONNREFUSED`, since now the service can be found.

#### Fixing SSL issues

Third, since you are now connecting to the blob storage service using a different domain name, the SSL certificate doesn't match any more, since it was issued for `local.wolkenkit.io`. As a result, you will get SSL errors when trying to connect.

The simplest way to get around this is to disable any SSL checks (albeit this is also the most insecure way to handle this!). How to do this depends on the HTTP client module you are using. E.g., in [request](https://github.com/request/request) there is an option called `strictSSL` that you can set to `false`.

Of course, what you *actually* should do is to either use a custom certificate which includes this domain name as well, or to write a function that handles the certificate check and accepts the presented one, especially in this case.

If you do all of this, things should work :-)

*PS: I am one of the authors of wolkenkit. Thanks a lot for bringing up this issue, and we will take care of this in the future, to make storing blobs easier.*